# ffmpeg - Join two movies with different timebase

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've got hundred movies from two video sources. One is MP4 with 25 fps

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'MAH00607.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : MSNV
    minor_version   : 22675568
    compatible_brands: MSNVmp42isom
    creation_time   : 2017-06-14T20:20:24.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:12.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2795 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-4), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2664 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-06-14T20:20:24.000000Z
      handler_name    : Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-06-14T20:20:24.000000Z
      handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
```

Second is AVI 29.81 fps

```
[avi @ 0x561e6733c640] non-interleaved AVI
Input #0, avi, from 'V-0018.AVI':
  Duration: 00:00:11.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4571 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 4515 kb/s, 28.18 fps, 28.18 tbr, 28.18 tbn, 28.18 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, 1 channels, u8, 64 kb/s
```

Before concating movies I convert them using [this script](https://gist.github.com/T4ng10r/4f57212465a32172e4a4bb7a654fcd0e).
I result final, concated movie has incorrect time and after AVI movies (which are first in sequence) finish - movie freezes.
I'll tried [FFmpeg - Concat videos with different time base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701511/ffmpeg-concat-videos-with-different-time-base) and Mulvya suggestion to recode avi files without success.

Can you propose other solution?

Comment: The Videos in your linked topic only have different timebases but not different framerates. In your script i cannot detect that you change the framerate for one of your videos. Is there a reason why you do not do this? ...it is just a bad idea creating videos with varying framerate....

Comment: Honestly, script was made only to add timestamp in video and was used for only one format.
Now, I received movies recorded by different devices (MOV,MTS,AVI) and I need to do the same. I'm not skilled enough with ffmpeg to solve it by myself.
I tried recoding with -r 25 or -r 30 (to match to highest fps) - still no success.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For concat'ing videos there are a few properties that have to be equal. So before executing the concat, you better "normalize" or "format" all you inputs to share these properties:

- Video resolution (e.g. -vf scale=1280x720)
- Video framerate (framerate dont need to match, but the timescale. -video_track_timescale 60000)
- Video interlacing (e.g. deinterlace using -vf yadif)
- Video pixel format (e.g. -vf format=yuv420p)
- Video codec (e.g. -c:v libx264)
- Audio samplerate (e.g. -ar 48000)
- Audio channels and track / layout (e.g. -map 0:1 -ac 2)
- Audio codec(s) (e.g. -c:a aac)

You should be able to do this by just specifying all those parameters on your "normalizing" ffmpeg commandline. If you do not explictly specify one parameter, ffmpeg will attempt to copy the parameter from the input stream which would end up in again different formats for you.

A good start might be something like that:

```
ffmpeg -i %SOURCEFILE% -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -ac 2 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -vf format=yuv420p,scale=1280x720,yadif  -video_track_timescale 60000 -c:v libx264 "%OUTPUT%.mp4"
```

Above is not tested, but it gives you a rough idea about how the cmd has got to look like. -codec copy is by the way something you cannot use at all given that you receive totally unknown files on input.

After all your inputs appear to share all the above parameters, you should be able to proceed with concat.

Comment: For video, framerates need not match; only the timebase. In containers like MP4 with out-of-band storage of codec parameters, the other parameters you mentioned should match.

Comment: Thats true but it will be hard to detect this and react to it when dealing with "any" input. I think it is best for beginners to first get it working for all formats and then experiment with "what can i do to save CPU time" :-)

Comment: But forcing output framerate, as in your command, can lead to dropped/dupped frames. Better to skip that and insert `-video_track_timescale <some large static value>` for MP4/MOV output.

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly, please feel free to edit it as well if you still find it does not match. Thanks Mulvya

Comment: After normalization both movies had different pixelformat/profile. Forcing yuvj422p (-profile:v high422 -pix_fmt yuvj422p) allow me to cleanly concat them. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the timebase. Ffmpeg adds an offset to the streams in the second, but otherwise doesn't change their timestamps even though it should.

I have never been able to get any timebase-related options to do anything. What did work for me: copy to mkv, which has 1/1000 timebase for video streams (ffmpeg reports this as '1k tbn'). This makes all timestamps consistent. Then concat.

For normal purposes, webm and mkv are basically the same thing, but mkv accepts H.264 while webm currently doesn't.

Note that timestamps with any slight jitter from rounding can lead to dropped or duplicated frames with poorly-designed fps-changing filters.

I'm pasting this answer to both questions, don't know if that's allowed.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have different video framerates and both movies should be converted to equal framerate, for example, 25fps. Then you can join the movies.

When I was converting a lot of movies for myself, I used [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/), a GUI-powered tool which can be used to convert multiple formats. This app have an easy interface, so you shouldn't face any troubles with it.

So you can consider it as a good solution with GUI and result preview.